# Serverless Framework - deploying multiple AWS cloudfront distributions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, serverless-plugins

I want to have multiple (based on stage param) AWS cloudfront distribution.
So if **--stage dev** passed it would deploy a different CloudFront dist than **--stage qa**.
Each stage should update/create a distribution based on the stage params.

Is it possible to achieve with serverless.yml?

I have found the following plugin [*serverless-api-cloudfront*](https://github.com/Droplr/serverless-api-cloudfront) , not sure it will create additional distribution if domain name is changed, and not sure it is possible to add origins with this plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to achieve with serverless.yml?

Yes. Yes it's possible and it's already built in. Your config will be simpler if you use the plugin `serverless-api-cloudfront` (rather than declaring a `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` resource yourself). You will get one distribution-per-stage, without having to jump through any hoops.

** EDIT

Expanding on my original post: It does seem that the `serverless-api-cloudfront` plugin's README is lacking in usage examples (at the time of this writing). I do suggest that anyone reading this post should go to the plugin's github and help the author by PR'ing a better README.

Here's a link to a blog article I found that shows an example of how to write up a `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` directly in your serverless.yml. It's only 1 resource, so you may not even want to depend on a plugin anyway. https://medium.com/yld-blog/caching-in-with-cloudfront-using-serverless-5a174651ab14

Comment: thanks! but how can I add origins and behaviours to this distribution? not much documentation there?

Comment: @AlexPortnoy updated my original answer, but TL;DR go to this link for inspiration on configuring a `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` directly in your serverless.yml without any plugins. https://medium.com/yld-blog/caching-in-with-cloudfront-using-serverless-5a174651ab14

Comment: I also noticed that the plugin does create an api-gateway with the distribution. That I do not need / want. But the blog is great!